# sending ssh commands in rust and stream response

Tags: asynchronous, rust, ssh

I am trying to perform commands on a server I am connected to via SSH using rust. I want to be able to read the result of my commands (and stream every line that is printed on my server to my client after running the command). I tried multiple libs starting with ssh2, unfortunately it couldn't allow me to stream the responses. I heard about async_ssh2 and specifically async_ssh2_lite. I couldn't find many examples online but I could see a demo in an old fork by someone which I copied:

```rs
use crate::config::Config;

use std::io;
use std::net::SocketAddr;
use std::net::TcpStream;
use async_io::Async;
use async_ssh2_lite::AsyncSession;
use std::str::FromStr;

pub async fn execute_actions(config: Config, skip: Option<Vec<String>>) -> io::Result<()> {
    let addr = SocketAddr::from_str(&config.server.host).expect("Invalid host address format");
    let stream = Async::<TcpStream>::connect(addr).await?;
    let mut session = AsyncSession::new(stream, None)?;

    session.handshake().await?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work as I get an error on `.handshake()`:

```
the method `handshake` exists for struct `AsyncSession<Async<TcpStream>>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
`async_io::Async<std::net::TcpStream>: AsyncSessionStream`
```

I am not sure how to fix that, online people seemed to suggest that this was because the async-io feature was missing, but adding it doesn't help:

```ini
async-ssh2-lite = { version = "0.4.7", features = ["async-io", "tokio"] }
```